# Alternative to MySQL CASE/WHEN?

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to select some integer values in MySQL. Several of the values are zero, which I want to grab as an empty string, and grab the integer values when available.

So I have something like this:

```
SELECT CASE field WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE field, [repeat for other fields]
```

Is there any way to shorten this in the SQL query? Does MySQL support the ternary operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
select IF(field1=0,'',field1), ...
```

And if your fields are NULL, there's IFNULL

```
select IFNULL(field1,'')
```

Comment: It also seems to be faster than CASE/WHEN.